# Can i return String or List depending on the class parameter of a method in java generics

Tags: java, generics

and i would like to return a String or List depending on the parameters. BTW i am new to generics and i am trying to learn. Thanks in advance..

I want to call my class like this.

```
getVehicleInfos("test",1,String.class); // This will return a String

List<EVehicleInfo> vehicleList = null;
getVehicleInfos("test",1,vehicleList.getClass()); //This will return List<EVehicleInfo>
```

My Method so far

```
private <T> T getVehicleInfos(String companyid,Integer onlineFilter,Class<T> cls){
        List<EVehicleInfo> vehicleList;
        String returnString;

        //I want to check the Type of T 
        //But i am having a hard time writing the correct if condition
        /*
         if(T is String){
            return returnString;
        }else if(T is List<EVehicleInfo>){
            return vehicleList;
        }

        */


}
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes i could not figure out the correct if condition @ScaryWombat

Comment: Your approach could be made to work, because you are passing in the class information.  But, does it really make good sense to have a method return either a `String` or a `List`, depending on the inputs?  I vote for having separate methods to do this.

Comment: Why don't you define two methods: `getVehicleInfos(String companyid,Integer onlineFilter, String vehicleString)` and `getVehicleInfos(String companyid,Integer onlineFilter, List<EVehicleInfo> vehicleList)`?

Comment: I am trying to figure out if this could be done by Generics @LuCio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE <sup>(to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52812695/can-i-return-string-or-list-depending-on-the-class-parameter-of-a-method-in-java/52812817#comment92543566_52812817))</sup> :**

You must cast the value to `T` and then return it.

```
if (cls == String.class) {
    return (T) "Your String";
} else {
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    return (T) al;
}
```

---

Yes your method

```
private <T> T getVehicleInfos(String companyid, Integer onlineFilter, Class<T> cls)
```

will return the sent class type. Try

```
String s = getVehicleInfos("", 0, String.class);
List l = getVehicleInfos("", 0, java.util.List.class);
```

Comment: I could not figure out the if condition in getVehicleInfos method. How will i now T is actually a String. My problem is there